# Merge conflict in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, localdb

I've wanted to change my models and tables in project. I have some models now:  Product, ProductType, ProductComposition, ProductSize, ShoppingCart.
Product has FK (ProductType, ProductTypeId), others have FK to Product (ProductId, Product)

Also I have an InitData.cs file with Initialize method where I add some stuff in my table so I have something to work on. But there is the problem:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_ProductTypes_ProductTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "clothesstoredb", table "dbo.Products", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I don't clearly know why it occures, maybe I do something wrong with FK's in models? I'm just learning, so it's little bit hard to understand. 
Furthermore, my Guid cookie generation method also broke somehow. I can't see where the problem is, but cookies are empty and I can't add the GUID, even it worked before I changed models. I found this strange, because I didn't changed Startup.cs at all.

Here is my models.

```
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }       
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }       

        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
        public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class ProductType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ProductComposition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Cotton { get; set; }
        public int? Denim { get; set; }
        public int? Leather { get; set; }
        public int? Polyester { get; set; }
        public int? Nylon { get; set; }
        public int? Elastane { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ProductSize
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public bool S { get; set; }
        public bool M { get; set; }
        public bool L { get; set; }
        public bool XL { get; set; }
        public bool XXL { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class ShoppingCart
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Guid{ get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my InitData.cs, where have been occured the main problem:

```
public static class InitData
    {
        public static void Initialize(ClothesContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Products.Any())
            {
                context.Products.AddRange(
                   new Product
                   {
                       Id = 1,
                       BrandName = "Vans",
                       Name = "Лонгслив OTW RAGLAN",
                       Image = "https://a.lmcdn.ru/img600x866/V/A/VA984EMCRY32_1833129_1_v2.jpg",
                       Description = "Хлопковый лонгслив от Vans решен в контрастной бело-черной цветовой гамме. " +
                       "Детали: прилегающий крой, рукав 3/4, округлый вырез горловины, стильный принт на фронтальной стороне.",
                       Material = "Хлопок - 100%",
                       Price = 2151,
                       ProductTypeId = 3

                   },
                   new Product
                   {
                       BrandName = "United Colors of Benetton",
                       Name = "Рубашка",
                       Price = 2510,
                       Description = "Рубашка United Colors of Benetton выполнена из тонкого, приятного на ощупь материала. Модель приталенного кроя. " +
                       "Детали: отложной воротник, планка и манжеты на пуговицах, слегка удлиненная спинка.",
                       Image = "https://a.lmcdn.ru/img600x866/U/N/UN012EMVWY79_5145481_1_v4.jpg",
                       Material = "Хлопок - 68%, Нейлон - 28%, Эластан - 4%",
                       ProductTypeId = 4

                   },
                   new Product
                   {
                       BrandName = "Jordan",
                       Name = "Толстовка M J JUMPMAN FLEECE FZ",
                       Price = 5690,
                       Description = "Толстовка от спорт-бренда выполнена из хлопкового трикотажа. Модель прямого кроя. " +
                       "Детали: регулируемый капюшон, два кармана, манжеты и низ на резинки, застежка на молнию.",
                       Image = "https://a.lmcdn.ru/img600x866/J/O/JO025EMFNEV0_9024380_1_v1_2x.jpg",
                       Material = "Хлопок - 80%, Полиэстер - 20%",
                       ProductTypeId = 2
                   },
                   new Product
                   {
                       BrandName = "Burton Menswear London",
                       Name = "Футболка",
                       Price = 1430,
                       Description = "Футболка из 100% хлопка.",
                       Image = "https://a.lmcdn.ru/img600x866/B/U/BU014EMFIHX0_8767196_1_v1.jpg",
                       Material = "Хлопок - 100%",
                       ProductTypeId = 1
                   }

                );


            }

            if (!context.ProductTypes.Any())
            {
                context.ProductTypes.AddRange(
                    new ProductType {                        
                        Description = "Футболки"
                    },
                    new ProductType
                    {                        
                        Description = "Худи"
                    },
                    new ProductType
                    {                        
                        Description = "Лонгсливы"
                    },
                    new ProductType
                    {

                        Description = "Рубашки"
                    }            
                    );

            }
            if (!context.ProductSizes.Any())
            {
                context.ProductSizes.AddRange(
                    new ProductSize
                    {
                        ProductId = 1,
                        XL = false,
                        L = true,
                        M = false,
                        S = false,
                        XXL = true
                    },
                    new ProductSize
                    {
                        ProductId = 2,
                        XL = true,
                        L = true,
                        M = true,
                        S = false,
                        XXL = true
                    },
                    new ProductSize
                    {
                        ProductId = 3,
                        XL = true,
                        L = false,
                        M = false,
                        S = false,
                        XXL = true
                    },
                    new ProductSize
                    {
                        ProductId = 4,
                        XL = false,
                        L = true,
                        M = false,
                        S = false,
                        XXL = true
                    }

                    );


            }
            if (!context.ProductCompositions.Any())
            {
                context.ProductCompositions.AddRange(
                    new ProductComposition
                    {
                        ProductId = 1,
                        Cotton = 100
                    },
                    new ProductComposition
                    {
                        ProductId = 2,
                        Cotton = 68,
                        Nylon = 28,
                        Elastane = 4
                    },
                    new ProductComposition
                    {
                        ProductId = 3,
                        Cotton = 80,
                        Polyester = 20
                    },
                    new ProductComposition
                    {
                        ProductId = 4,
                        Cotton = 100
                    }

                );


            }
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

I expected the DB structure where I can set Type of clothes by ProductTypeId, sizes by using boolean values in Size table and Composition with int? values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MERGE statement is trying to insert a record which doesn't have a corresponding record in the parent table hence the error. You need to make sure

You need to seed your children entities (like `ProductType` table) firstly and use `context.SaveChanges()` to save the data firstly.Then you seed the `Product` entities with existing `ProductTypeId` and also remember to use `context.SaveChanges()`.

Besides, if you would like to supply a value for the `Key` manually , you need to add below attribute on the field:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Otherwise it will increase as 1,2...

Refer to [EF Core Generated Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties)